# Проблема с высотой DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-xml

DialogFragment выглядит вот так (под кнопками непонятное пространство)

[image: Диалог]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleITextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_period_lbl"
        android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/start"
            android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/startDateEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/end"
            android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/endDateEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border_radius"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.06" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border_radius"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как видно высота указана wrap_content

Код:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_custom_period, container);
    initView(content);
```

Ничего касающегося разметки дальше нету

Помогите пожалуйста понять где проблема.

Comment: может там просто пустое пространство? попробуйте вставить туда textView с текстом каким-то, или вам нужно чтобы вся ваша конструкция находилась по центру экрана?

Comment: Да
диалог должен быть по центру
И там нет пустого пространства
в пред смотре xml выглядит правильно (без пустого пространства снизу)

Comment: попробуйте заменить в главном linearlayout высоту с wrap_content на match_parent может поможет

Comment: Изменил высоту на match_parent - не помогло

Comment: а layout gravity center пробовали?

Comment: Да и layout gravity center тоже не помогает

Comment: а просто gravity?

Comment: Смог исправить жестко задав высоту контейнера с кнопками

Comment: А на остальных устройствах нормально выглядит?

Comment: Между двух button, стоит view - не вижу его на скрине...И странно что в нем "android:layout_width" два раза назначаешь разные значения, одно лишнее,я думаю. Может в нем дело?